# Unable to set background image width and height of component

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component that i am passing a slot to. I am also setting background image that works fine but when i try to set the size of backgorund image it don't work.  Here is what i have tried

I have a draggable componengt that i am trying to set backgorund image background image get's set but the size don't work.

```
<VueDragResize
        v-for="(rect, index) in rects"
        :key="index"
        :w="rect.width"
        :h="rect.height"
        :x="rect.left"
        :y="rect.top"
        :parentW="listWidth"
        :parentH="listHeight"
        :axis="rect.axis"
        :isActive="rect.active"
        :minw="rect.minw"
        :minh="rect.minh"
        :isDraggable="rect.draggable"
        :isResizable="rect.resizable"
        :parentLimitation="rect.parentLim"
        :snapToGrid="rect.snapToGrid"
        :aspectRatio="rect.aspectRatio"
        :z="rect.zIndex"
        v-on:activated="activateEv(index)"
        v-on:deactivated="deactivateEv(index)"
        v-on:dragging="changePosition($event, index)"
        v-on:resizing="changeSize($event, index)"
        @click.native="getindex(index)"
      >
        <div
          class="filler"
          :style="{background:rect.color,backgroundsize: '30px' }"
        >{{rect.text}}{{rect.recipientname}}</div>
      </VueDragResize>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `backgroundSize` with capital S

```
        <div
          class="filler"
          :style="{background:rect.color,backgroundSize: '30px' }"
        >{{rect.text}}{{rect.recipientname}}</div>
```